# What happened to Misa Amane in the last episode?

Tags: death-note

In the last episode of *Death Note*, the series, we see Misa Amane standing near the edge of a building. She incurred a lot of grief due to Light Yagami's death; after all, she was one of the most devoted to him. She went through continuous torture and suffered for light.

Did Misa commit suicide?

Answer (score 16):

This write-up over at [WikiAnswers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Does_misa_amane_kill_herself) is pretty good.

> According to 13: How to Read, Misa loses her memories related to using the Death Note and retains her love for Light. Since it is in the nature of a Death Note user to "suffer misfortune", Misa falls into despair after someone "like Matsuda" "probably let it slip" that Light died. When she regains her memories by Rem telling her Rem states that if Light tries to harm Misa in anyway she will kill him. Misa responds "I don't exactly want to be loved by a Shinigami, and if Light died I couldn't live on without him. There's no way Light would kill Misa-Misa. And why would you go so far for me." Most likely foreshadowing events to come because Light does die. Despite fan rumors, the cloaked woman who appears at the end of the manga is not Misa, but an unnamed follower of Kira. Misa's fate is not shown in the manga at all; she was last seen staying at the Teito Hotel. Ohba stated that this was simply because he did not have a situation to fit her in.

It may be that the scene from the anime is in the future, because light dies on April 28, 2010, and Misa died on February 14, 2011 (Valentines Day) according to Chapter 110 "How To Read" profiles of the characters.

There's no clear evidence for the suicide on the roof, but there's really little reason someone would be standing on the edge of a roof, on the other side of the safety railing.

Comment: this is regarding the anime series, where light dies on Jan 28, 2013 and Misa is standing on a roof in the last scene.

Comment: Would she be committing suicide out of choice or could she have been forced to by the Death Note? Perhaps Near decided to finish her off himself? She certainly had a strange glassy look in her eyes.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's strongly implied that she committed suicide. (in the Anime)

There's actually two things going on:

- Yes, she was grieving for Yagami's death.
- She also had her remaining lifespan cut in half twice from two eye trades. Once with Rem and once with Ryuk.

Having halved her life twice, it's hardly a coincidence that she would die so quickly. The fact that there's a concept of "remaining lifespan" already implies some sort of predetermination in the series.

Comment: So u mean to say that as she had the long lifespan given by Rem to her, she COULDN'T die??

Comment: No, I'm saying that she cut her original lifespan in half twice. So it's not at all a surprise that she would die before the series ended.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that Misa had halved her life twice, since Rem intervened to prevent her death, provoking her own death, but skipping Misa's prematured ending.

Comment: We don't know how much life Rem had when she saved Misa, and that was the second shinigami to save Misa as well, so her life was extended twice.  We don't know how much life they gave her, it could work out that she had quite a bit left even after the eye deals.

Comment: Comment from an anon (invalid) edit: "However this is all invalid because Rem first explains to her that when a shinigami is killed for a human their remaning life span is sent to said human."

Comment: I was gonna say it does not matter about the eye deals twice, 2 shinigami died to save her and what happens is the shinigami's lifespan is transferred to th the human they save it tells you that when you find out how to kill a sinigami so she already had an inordinate lifespan before the first eye deal she might have been down to a small life span until REM kills L to save her.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rem killed herself to extend Misa's life, all of Rem's remaining life would have been added to hers, just like when the first Shinigami saved her. If that is the case, then her getting her life span halved twice would have been wouldn't be such a big deal. Her life span was extended again AFTER she halved it twice.

Answer (score 1):

We know that if a shinigami saves a human then that human gets the rest of the life span, then Misa gets that halved with the eye deal from Rem. Rem then saves Misa and Misa gets Rem's remaining life span, and then it is halved by Ryuk. So still she has a pretty long life span. And just as my observation the girl at the end is Misa for the fact that if you look back earlier on in the series Misa wears that same outfit in one of the episodes, but like I said that is just my observation.

Comment: But you're assuming that Rem had a ton of "life" left...

Comment: @Darius But that was also the second shinigami to save Misa, Gelus did as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you kill a shinigami you don't get the rest of their lives because in reality Shinigami can't really die. They're pretty much immortal until they sacrifice their lives for a human. When Rem killed "L" and "Watari" Rem just saved Misa from dying from them. Rem didn't give it's remaining life to Misa. Rem just allowed Misa to live a little longer. This is shown when the story is first given to Misa when she asks Rem "How do you kill a Shinigami?"